# Get an unsigned int milliseconds out of chrono::duration

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

For a winapi wrapper I want to use chrono for a duration given to the call. The code example:

```
bool setTimer(std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::milliseconds> duration)
{
    unsigned int dwDuration = Do some chrono magic here

    SetTimer(m_hWnd,1,dwDuration,0);
}
```

dwDuration has to be in milliseconds.

First question: How do to the magic.

Second question: Is the parameter declaration okay?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The name of the type is `std::chrono::milliseconds`, and it has a member function `count()` that returns the number of those milliseconds:

```
bool setTimer(std::chrono::milliseconds duration)
{
    unsigned int dwDuration = duration.count();
    return std::cout << "dwDuration = " << dwDuration << '\n';
}
```

online demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03f29d41e9bd260c

If you want to be ultra-pedantic, the return type of count() is `std::chrono::milliseconds::rep`

If you want to deal with fractional milliseconds, then the type would be `std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>` (and the return type of count() is then double)

Comment: @MartinSchlott note that functions that take durations are typically function templates, parametrized on duration's parameters, e.g. [std::this_thread::sleep_for()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for). In such function, you could `duration_cast` to milliseconds. Your function is only callable with the durations that are implicitly convertible to milliseconds (such as `seconds`)

Comment: That was intentionally as I want to be close to the winapi. But what kind of parameter type do you suggest? Or do I have to turn the function into a template? The target winapi function of course only accepts milliseconds.

Comment: Depends on the interface you want. It's your choice according to your requirements. I don't think there's a general best option. If you put milliseconds in the interface, the caller is forced to handle truncation/rounding itself (which means they get to choose); if you put a template, you have make that choice yourself.

Comment: With my IDE `std::chrono::milliseconds` type is not `std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>` but `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::milli>`

Comment: @Gugelhupf of course. I wasn't even talking about std::chrono::milliseconds when I mentioned the type double.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code:

```
auto now = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

auto timeMillis = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Comment: Please do not use the "auto" keyword inside explanations. I know that is common sense, but I am not a compiler, I do not know the return type. Is timeMillis of type unsigned int? Also, it is not a direct answer to my question as I have already a duration, not a time_point.

Comment: By invoking count() he is forming an integer and not a duration.   To your point this is masked by auto, but just in defense of his answer.