# Chrono timer in C++ to double

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

How can i create a timer that after a certain duration, it does something? so far i have been trying to use the % operation. I made a timer at the start of the function and subtracted the current time (now()function) then i % the difference by 5 because i want 5 seconds to pass:

```
(at the start of the program i defined start as high_resolution_clock::now())
duration<double> dur = start-high_resolution_clock::now();
if(dur%5==0)
```

the error ive been getting is: no operator "==" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::chrono::duration> == int

Comment: duration has a member count() to return the number of milliseconds. See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785687/get-an-unsigned-int-milliseconds-out-of-chronoduration, or try a simple web search "Chrono to int" - that's what I did...

Comment: % (modulus operator) can be used only with integer numbers. You can try to use the 'long long int' type (int64_t or uint64_t). With this int  you get an integer of 64bits and the modulus operator will work fine.

Comment: What is the **first** error you get?  I get the error about operator==, but it isn't the first error.

Comment: i would suggest you run it on a separate thread, have an loop in there that runs the code you want to run every 5 seconds - sleep five seconds after it ran it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for something like:

```
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    bool condition = true;
    while (condition) {
        auto time_passed = high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        if( time_passed % 5s == 0s ) {
            // do your thing every 5 seconds
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Code version 1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a13083aa01b339e), [Code version 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/439c4c9a3766957d)

---

### Explanation

**The modulo**

The [modulo operation for duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4) called with: `duration % x` expects `x` to be either of the two:

- ***another duration***, in which case chrono does the job for you in getting the common type of `duration` and `x`, that would allow modulo.
- ***some arbitrary type***, in which case the inner type of `duration` should be able to perform modulo with `x`. Which is not the case for `duration` that is based on `<double>`.

To allow modulo on `duration` that is based on `<double>` there is a need to use `duration_cast` or to use the first modulo option above, with another `duration`.

**The comparison**

The modulo operation returns a `duration` as can be seen in the reference. To compare it to an `int` (i.e. 0) there is a need to turn it into an `int` (since `duration` and `int` are not comparable) and this can be done with a call to count, e.g.:

```
if ( (time_passed % 5s).count() == 0 )
```

Alternatively we can compare it to an actual duration as we do above.

---

### An important design note

Even though above code works and when we reach the exact modulo we will do the thing, the value the `duration` is counting is not in seconds, so if we just missed the 5 seconds by 2 nanos we will miss the modulo check and would not do our thing, then we will wait for the next round and would most probably miss it again. Modulo is a very bad choice for trying to catch the time, as the time that we sample jumps. A better approach would be to calculate that there has been 5 seconds or more since we last did the thing as a trigger. Which can be achieved with this code:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto last_time_we_did_the_thing = start;
    bool condition = true;
    while (condition) {
        auto curr_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto time_since_last_do_the_thing
           = curr_time - last_time_we_did_the_thing;
        if( time_since_last_do_the_thing >= 5s ) {
            // do your thing every 5 seconds
            last_time_we_did_the_thing = curr_time;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Code ^](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13b75f48feb162b1)

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained _why_.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings would try. Having now Howard Hinnant on the page makes me a bit cold feet :-) at least if I'm wrong I'll have someone to watch over.

Comment: the code you put in the link doesnt wait 5 seconds, i tried to run it and it keeps running the code in the if statement without waiting the 5 seconds

Comment: @xxsurajbxx it indeed doesn't wait 5 sec, you can add a sleep to test it, suggesting for an online compiler test to use smaller sleep time than 5 seconds, otherwise the online compiler may get your program off.

Comment: You're doing fine. :-)  But can you rewrite it without using `.count()`?

Comment: Also, `time_passed` is probably intended to a be a positive amount.

Comment: Much better!  That was my upvote btw.  Now you just need to clean up your explanation a little. :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant done! a private tutorial with Howard Hinnant on `std::chrono`, +upvote bonus :-) what an honor and a delight!

Comment: Oh, just noticed another problem:  The odds that the clock is going to stop on exactly a multiple of 5s is extraordinarally low.  E.g. one iteration is going to come in at 4.999999999s, and the next at 5.000000001

Comment: @HowardHinnant that's totally right. I also thought about that. I will add a note.

Comment: Oh this is much better now. Though we usually call it "modulo" not "modulu".