# comparing against time with chrono c++

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I want to pretty much say "as long as we are under a certain time, continue to iterate"

the code for this looks like

```
int time = atoi(argv[1]);
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
while((std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count()) < time){
            /*perform operation*/
  }
```

However I am unable to compare against time like this and get the error `error: conversion to ‘double’ from ‘std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >::rep {aka long int}’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]`

does anyone know how to compare with the less than operator using chrono?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. It should only be a few more lines of code. A declaration of `time` would be helpful, for example.

Comment: this may help https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477360/chrono-timer-in-c-to-double

Comment: works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/48djso please provide a [mre]

Comment: If you google "Howard Hinnant chrono" you can find a lot of material on how to use chrono including videos etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int time = atoi(argv[1]);
```

What units is `time`?  `seconds`?  `nanoseconds`?  For this answer I'll assume `seconds`, but change it to whatever you need:

```
std::chrono::seconds time{atoi(arv[1])};
```

Next:

```
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

`high_resolution_clock` is going to be a type alias to either `system_clock` or `steady_clock`.  [The top of this answer explains the difference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31553641/576911)  I recommend chosing `system_clock` or `steady_clock`, depending on your needs, rather than letting the vendor choose for you.

```
while((std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count()) < time){
            /*perform operation*/
  }
```

- Always try to stay within the chrono type system, instead of exiting it using `.count()`.  Once you exit the chrono library, it can no longer help you.  In this case it means doing the comparison using chrono units instead of `int`s.
- When comparing chrono units, one does not need to cast such that both sides of the comparison are the same units.  It is ok to compare `seconds` and `milliseconds` for example.  chrono will do the comparison correctly, taking into account the different units.

I like to issue a function-scope `using namespace std::chrono` as I find repeated `std::chrono::` overly verbose, making the code harder to read.

```
using namespace std::chrono;
seconds time{atoi(arv[1])};
auto start = steady_clock::now();
while(steady_clock::now() - start < time)
{
     // perform operation
}
```

Or you can algebraically rearrange this:

```
while(steady_clock::now() < start + time)
{
     // perform operation
}
```

Noticing the "constant" on the rhs, you can collect and rename that:

```
auto finish = steady_clock::now() + seconds{atoi(arv[1])};
while(steady_clock::now() < finish)
{
     // perform operation
}
```

All of the above are equivalent, so you can choose whichever one you find more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the precedence, you cast is performed after `count()` function, this cause that the cast is over a `double` value.

The problem can be solved in this way:

```
int time = atoi(argv[1]);
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
while(((std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start)).count()) < time){
            /*perform operation*/
  }
```